# Where is the unary operator and the operand here?

Tags: javascript, unary-operator

```
if (document .getElementByid('header'))
    // Found: do something
} else {
    // Not found: do something else
}
```

In "JavaScript and JQuery: Interactive Front-End Web Development" by Jon Duckett it is written:

> Because the presence of an object or array can be considered truthy, it is often used to check for the existence of an element within a page.
>
> A unary operator returns a result with just one operand. Here you can see an if statement checking for the presence of an element. If the element is found, the result is truthy, so the first set of code is run. If it is not found, the second set is run instead.

Is the writer means that the if keyword is considered a unary operator and the `document.getElementById('header')` is the operand ?

Comment: I don't see a unary operator there. An example of a unary operator would be `var1 = -var2`, the `-` is a unary operator that negates its operand.

Comment: I think the author means `getElementById()`, but it is a method, not an operator.

Comment: Whatever the author meant, it seems like he's ideosyncratic.

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4 lists the unary operators: `delete`, `void`, `typeof`, `++`, `--`, `+`, `-`, `~`, `!`.

Comment: I feel the first sentence doesn't have anything to do with the rest of the paragraph.

Answer (score -1):

<s>The operator is the 
 `if`, the operand (on which the operator operates) is in this case `document .getElementByid('header')`</s>

`+` for example is a binary operator, it has two operands, for example in `a+b` they would be `a` and `b`. Unary means, that you only have one operand.

EDIT:

As Barmar pointed out, `if` does not produce a result and therfore I would not call it an operator. My bad, didn't think it through

Comment: `if` is not considered an operator, it's a keyword of a statement. Operators are parts of expressions, and `if` is not an expression.

Comment: But maybe that book is using nonstandard terminology.

Comment: I guess, you could certainly argue, that it is an operator. It takes one argument and produces a result

Comment: I understand the difference between unary and binary operators. I'm here confused because i didn't know or i didn't see before that the if keyword is considered a unary operator

Comment: @PeterFischaleck It doesn't produce a result. You can't write `var = if(condition) value;`

Comment: FWIW, `+` also exist as unary version: `var foo = +bar;`